# I see my object glossy in viewport shading but when rendered solid grey color

Tags: modeling

I am making a table in Blender. When it's not rendered it's glossy because I put a Glossy shader on it. But when rendered it's just a color.

I have tried everything. I have literally done everything I could find but nothing worked. I have tried texture coordinates. Nothing worked all of the research. The background I have done. Didn't help.

I have tried making a new shader and see if it works but it didn't. When I changed the material color it was just a color with no glossiness.

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Which render engine do you use? Cycles or Eevee? Have you set up an HDRI as background?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Material Shading mode has a preview world texture that sows up in your reflection because it's a Shading Mode designed for quick material preview.

When you switch to Rendered Shading Mode, you see your scene as it is, which by default has a pure grey world material with no texture. Hence, nothing to see in an object's reflection, besides a pure grey which may make it seem reflection-less.

Add an environment texture, a sky texture, or just other objects around, and you will see your reflections work just fine ; when there are visible things to reflect.